# В чем различие между Spring Framework и Spring Boot

Tags: spring, java

Необходимо написать сайт с использованием Spring и Hibernate. 
Что лучше выбрать для первого раза: Spring Framework или Spring Boot?

Comment: @wss-world, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему и т. д.

Comment: Просто хочу услышать совет, с чего лучше начать изучение Spring. И вообще где меньше прийдется писать спагетти xml !

Comment: Сегодня можно использовать [start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io/) для генерации типичного проекта.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Не уверен в том, насколько хорошо вы представляете разницу между Spring Boot и Spring MVC, поэтому попробую объяснить.

Spring MVC это фреймворк для разработки Web приложений. Внутри себя он использует Spring Core (т.е. все компоненты, как ваши так и самого фреймворка, являются бинами в контейнере, который управляет как их жизненным циклом, так и их зависимостями).

Причем здесь, Spring Boot? Для того, чтобы развернуть типичное приложение на Spring MVC и, скажем, Hibernate от вас, как от программиста, потребуется написать некоторое количество кода. Причем, как правило, у стандартных проектов этот конфигурационный код одинаков. Для того, чтобы упростить жизнь разработчикам и новичкам, которые сходу не могут настроить проект, появился проект Spring Boot. Он имеет заранее подготовленные куски конфигурации, которые активируются в зависимости от различных условий. Например, если у вас в classpath есть Hibernate, то бины для работы Spring и Hibernate настраиваются автоматически. Если у вас в classpath есть  JAR файл для работы с БД H2, то она автоматически разворачивается и Hibernate настраивается для работы c ней. И т.д. для различных компонентов.

Итого. Возможно, что вам стоит попробовать spring-boot, т.к. в нём, скорее всего, придётся писать меньше кода для настройки всего этого хозяйства. Но, если вам понадобится немного нестандартная конфигурация, а знания Spring Framework недостаточные, то могут возникнуть проблемы, с тем как это настроить.

Решать, разумеется, вам.

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение!

Comment: @Slava Semushin Если boot это всего лишь штука для перичной настройки приложения, то зачем она нам в зависимостях проекта? в онлайне выбрал нужные галочки, оно создало нужный помник, структуру проекта и вперед. Не понимаю зачем зависимость на spring-boot в помнике

Comment: @gstackoverflow Нет, это не первичная настройка приложения. Куски кода из Spring Boot используются при каждом запуске (некоторые и во время работы) вашего приложения. В отличие от Spring Roo он не генерирует код в виде файлов, это специальные бины, которые при запуске определяют окружение и в зависимости от остальных dependecies активируют те или иные функции приложения.

Comment: @Slava Semushin А может так случиться, что мне надо как-то хитро настроить приложение, что boot этого не позволяет а обычный спринг позволяет?  уменьшает ли гибкость boot?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Spring Boot не заменяет Spring, а дополняет его. Поэтому, если Spring Boot чего-то не позволяет, то вы можете без проблем использовать Spring.

Answer (score 8):

Spring Boot был создан, чтобы не писать на xml. Вот вам конфиг 2-ух бинов.
Писать проще, приятнее, надежнее. Сам начинал изучение Spring именно с MVC.
Сейxас при виде XML идет кровь из глаз :-). 
Вся конфигурация на Java. Много вещей идет из коробки. Например вы подключили зависимость БД, например mySQL, и можете всего-лишь указать URL, USER, PASSWORD в application.properties - все, БД настроена. Без всяких доп. настроек.

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
```

Spring Boot это следуюший шаг Spring, чтобы сделать его легче в настройке и развитии  приложений. С Spring Boot конфигурации Spring  минимизируется максимально.

Answer (score 7):

Я бы решал так: если нужен рабочий код как можно быстрее, то однозначно Boot, но если есть время и желание немного почитать (там дня хватит с головой), то лучше начать со старого доброго Spring Framework - будет больше понимания "как оно всё работает".
Можно ещё так рассматривать:

1. Spring Core сам по себе запускает бины, отлично, понятно, просто,
   дофига конфигов в xml.
2. Spring + схемы создают дефолтовые бины, которые можно найти в схемах
   и переопределить по необходимости - для понимания иногда нужно
   залезть в схему, но сильно меньше писать в xml.
3. Spring Boot - дофига магии, создающей бины направо и налево, и
   отследить какие именно создались... ну тоже наверное как-то можно,
   но ещё один слой автоматики.