# Для чего используется Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Объясните в каких случаях целесообразно использовать Spring Boot framework в дополнении к Spring?

И какие его основные features?

Comment: Возможно, что вам будет интересен этот ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/318146/В-чем-различие-между-spring-framework-и-spring-boot/318151#318151

Comment: Если вы не можете найти ответ на этот вопрос самостоятельно, то предлагаю следующую стратегию -- используйте только Spring. И в процессе столкнетесь с тем, что то, что вам нужно делается так, а в Spring Boot вот так. Со временем вы поймете сами зачем нужен Spring Boot и сможете осмысленно на него смигрировать. Либо можете на заморачиваться и просто начать его использовать.

Comment: Spring Boot - это фреймворк для менеджмента всех спринговых фреймворков (которых стало очень много). Он очень сильно завязан на conventions и умолчания, благодаря чему как любой CoC-инструмент позволяет легко сконфигурировать Spring под стандартное веб-приложение и отдаётся болью при каждом отклонении от линии партии.

Comment: @Nofate Вы вообще о какой боли говорите? Если Вы в состоянии конфигурировать Spring то Вы можете также и Spring Boot сконфигурировать. Зачем людей-то путаете?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot сделан для того, чтобы у разработчика было больше свободного времни, которое он бы мог посвятить просматриванию демотиваторов вместо тупой и рутинной работы, вроде поиска проблем в pom файле и xml-конфигураций. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ответ выше не является плохим.
Spring Boot просто позволяет с минимальными настройками сделать готовый проект на фреймворке Spring.